# How to store a multiple row query in a session var and use it with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, session

*I'm trying to carry my SQL query from PHP Controller file to my PHP View file. I've been cudgeling my brain for hours and hours. I've discovered that my major problem is that I don't know to carry data from PHP to **another** document that didn't start the REQUEST petition. The PHP Controller code (request) comes from a submit of other document (votar1.php).

I know to do it only if I pressed a button (type button) with onclick, but no idea when the code is triggered by submit button. Embbeding javascript on php doesn't works for me in any way.*

**↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ (Focus on this better). ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓**

Buuut, I think I'm close to the solution now, I've been experimenting with storing a query in a SESSION, so I would prefer this solution. It seems simple when the query returns you only one row, but when it returns more than one row, I don't know how to deal with it. So I need to know:

- How to store multiple row query in a SESSION
- How to use it (↑) to show data in a table using foreach.

I would be very thankful if you guide me a bit about these 2 things mentioned above ↑ (please, don't forget about the second one, because I don't know how to deal with that).

**Controller(controladorPartidos.php):**

```
include 'conexionBBDD.php';
session_start();
----other code----      
if (passwordMatch($nif, $password) && (!haVotado($nif))) { //si la contraseña es correcta y no ha votado...
        $consulta = "SELECT LOGO, NOMBRE FROM partido";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
               $query=array_push($_SESSION['query'], $rows);
        }
        header('Location: Vista/votar2.php');
}
```

**PHP View (votar2.php):**

```
<?php
include_once 'header.html';
session_start();
$query = $_SESSION['query'];
?>  
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="caja">
        <form action="../controladorPartidos.php" name="formVotar2" id="formVotar2" method="post">
            <table>
                <?php foreach ($query as $partido) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><img src="<?php echo $partido[0] ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="partido" value="<?php echo $partido[1] ?>"><?php echo $partido[1] ?></td>

                    <?php }; ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="width:75px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;">
                <br/>
                <input id="botonVotar" type="submit" name="submit" onClick="submitVoto()" value="Votar"/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me! Thank you in advance for your time :)

Comment: Why do you need to redundantly store db results in the session? What's about storing the SQL or its parameters and query again as needed? Is it a remote db on a slow / heavy loaded connection? Are you actually using the result on both pages?

Comment: For snapshots consider also "temporary" tables. (not MySql's temporary table type which is dropped on closing the session)

Comment: I don't know other way to carry my query result.... that's why I'm using sessions. 
I also know to carry my query result only if I use onclick > AJAXFunction (with document.getElementById), but I don't know to call JSfunctions when I use SUBMIT, altought the much I've searched for it, nothing worked for me. I feel kinda stupid :/

Comment: How large is the result? Or how large can it grow in future?

Comment: Although your current approach is really bad. but if you still want to store multiple rows in session, then you can json_encode your query response and set that in session. And when you want to use that, you just need to json_decode and you will be able to use that.

Comment: It returns 6 rows. But I will need to develop another similar for more rows D: